# Is there projected version of EPSG:4269?

Tags: coordinate-system, north-america

I know EPSG:4269 is a datum so this question might not make sense.

Is there a CRS which uses NAD83 and uses meters instead of degrees (something like EPSG:6933 but for NAD83)?

https://epsg.org/search/by-name/query/NAD83%28HARN/sessionkey/7ti4mn2lcn/crs_sort_by/revisiondate/crs_sort_dir/asc#datum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the UTM's across North America have a NAD83 version.
https://epsg.io/26914